# how do I insert a character into a string at a specific location but only counting letters in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringi

I am trying to create a df where I add a character into a string at a position defined by another column- but I only want the code to count letters and not numbers or other characters while it does this, hopefully the example tables make this clearer

my initial data looks like this.

| String | Insert_pos |
| --- | --- |
| PEPTIDE | 3 |
| PE[+10]TIDE | 3 |

i use the  following code

```
library(stringi)
stri_sub(df$String,df$Insert_pos+1, df$insert_pos-1) <- "[+20]"
```

and it only half works--- I only want it to count the Letters and not the numbers already added when it adds the new characters. as shown below

| what I get | What I want |
| --- | --- |
| PEP[+20]TIDE | PEP[+20]TIDE |
| PE[[+20]+10]TIDE | PE[+10]P[+20]TIDE |

I think the way to do it would be to specify to only count letters, but I cant find how to specify this in Stringi/ not sure if it is possible.

Any help would be great,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub`:

```
sub("(([[:alpha:]][^[:alpha:]]*){3})", "\\1[+20]", df$String)
#[1] "PEP[+20]TIDE"     "PE[+10]T[+20]IDE"
```

In this case using only upper case will also work.

```
sub("(([A-Z][^A-Z]*){3})", "\\1[+20]", df$String)

sub("(([[:upper:]][^[:upper:]]*){3})", "\\1[+20]", df$String)
```

Taking the positions from *Insert_pos*:

```
mapply(function(s, n) sub(paste0("(([[:alpha:]][^[:alpha:]]*){", n, "})"),
                          "\\1[+20]", s), df$String, df$Insert_pos)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for this solution, Im not to familiar with this style of coding in R, but its been good to try and learn about it. Is there away to change the   *){3})",  bit so that it draws the position information from a column. I tried just shoehorning df$insertpos into the {brackets} but it didnt like it, i guess not too suprisingly.  again thanks for your input

Comment: In that case use e.g. mapply - see update.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the value of your `df$Insert_pos` column for the next possible position:

```
df <- data.frame(
  String = c("PEPTIDE", "PE[+10]TIDE"),
  Insert_pos = c(3,3)
)

df$Insert_pos <- ifelse(
  stri_sub(df$String,df$Insert_pos, df$Insert_pos) %in% c("[", "]", "+", 1:9), 
  df$Insert_pos + 5 , 
  df$Insert_pos)

library(stringi)
stri_sub(df$String,df$Insert_pos+1, df$Insert_pos-1) <- "[+20]"

df
```

This gives you then:

```
            String Insert_pos
1     PEP[+20]TIDE          3
2 PE[+10]T[+20]IDE          8
```

Comment: Yeah this works really nicely, It struggles when there are say multiple {+20] inserts before the insert position, but that is super uncommon. Thanks for taking the time to answer this :)